# how can I find the leftmost topmost point when the leftmost point has multiple instances?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am using OpenCV to find the extreme points of a the contour for an inflated bubble.The contour is the white portion of the bubble. After binarising the image and applying thresholding, I extract the contours and then find the extreme left and right point of the contour. To do this I apply the argmin and argmax function to the numpy array of contour coordinates. The issue is that the rightmost point has a few pixels that are in a straight vertical line. Because of this the argmax() function selects only the first instance of the rightmost point and this is not aligned to the leftmost y value resulting in a slight error in the chord length.

I need the selection of leftmost and rightmost points to be aligned on the y axis if there are multiple instances on that axis. This must only happen if there are points that lay on the same axis. If not then just provide the first instance as it currently does.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

```py
#The binarised thresholded image is passed through the following functions to obtain the contour and then the point. I have excluded the method for thresholding. 

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts)

#There are two contours identified. One for the aruco marker and the other for the bubble. Select only the bubble contour

c = cnts[1]

# compute the extreme points of the contour

extLeft = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
extRight = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
extTop = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
extBot = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

# draw the outline of the object, then draw each of the
# extreme points, where the left-most is red, right-most
# is green, top-most is blue, and bottom-most is teal
cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)
cv2.circle(image, extLeft, 4, (0, 0, 255), -1)
cv2.circle(image, extRight, 4, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(image, extTop, 1, (255, 0, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(image, extBot, 1, (255, 100, 0), -1)
# show the output image
chord = (dist.euclidean(extLeft,extRight ))/pixelsPerMetric
height = int(extTop[1]-extBot[1])/pixelsPerMetric
print(chord)
print(height)
cv2.putText(image, "{:.1f}mm".format(chord),extLeft, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.65, (255, 255, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
fname="extreme.jpg"


print(extLeft)
print(extBot)
print(extRight)


cv2.imwrite(fname, image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I find the extreme points using the argmin() and argmax() function on the contour numpy array x and y co-ordinates as per the OpenCV examples. This only looks at the x and y co-ords separately and selects only the first instance as described in the numpy documentation. I have tried using the numpy .where() function to locate the indices of all points but could not get it to work. Please can someone help

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and review the articles [ask] and [mre]

Comment: The red and the green dot don't really seem to be the leftmost and rightmost pixel of the bubble. Can you please explain? Do you need the chord always to be horizontal? Then why don't you simply count the pixels per row and take the maximum?

Comment: . The left and green dots are the leftmost and rightmost pixels of the contour shown in yellow not of the bubble. @Christoph I did realized the question needed more clarity so have expanded on the code and also tried to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The contour values are saved in an array of (x,y) coordinates. The array is ordered in an anticlockwise manner starting at the topmost pixel and since argmin() and argmax() select the first instance of the leftmost and rightmost pixel you end up with smallest y value for the leftmost x value and largest y value for the rightmost x value.

Also when drawing the contour using:

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE uses the minimum number of pixels to form the contour. So for a straight line there will be only two points. If cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE is used it will provide all pixels making up the contour.

Since only 4 pixels make up the vertical lines of the contour, to find the leftmost and rightmost pixel with the smallest y value you can just reverse the array when finding the rightmost value.

```
c = cnts[1]
c2 = c[::-1]
# compute the extreme points of the contour
extLeft = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
extRight = tuple(c2[c2[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
extTop = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
extBot = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
```